# Apply DSP per audio channel

Tags: windows, audio, windows-10

How can I apply theses DSPs in Windows per channel, i.e:

Channel Left: Apply a High Pass Filter

Channel Right: Apply a Band Pass Filter

In Linux I can simple accomplish this by using JACK routing capabilities + JAMin.

PS: I want this to be system-wide, so any application's audio will go throughout this setup.